# Jquery delay is not working

Tags: jquery, delay

Hello guys I am trying to do a simple animation with some delays in it but its not working please give me a hand. here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.detailsholder').hide()
    $(".detailsholder").animate({"top": '-520px'},1)
    $('.detailsholder').hide()
    $('.detailsholder').fadeIn(500)
    $('.detailsholder').delay(5000).animate({'top': "-260px",'easing': "easeInElastic"}, 400).delay(5000).('.detailsholder').animate({'top': "0px",'easing': "easeInElastic"},400);
});
```

Comment: Where are all your semicolons?

Comment: You should chain your jQuery statements.

Comment: : (. This is an example of bad influences of jQuery on knowledge of JavaScript.

Comment: are you guys going to help me get this thing working or are you doing to ask stupid questions? i obviously don't understand JQuery like you do. and need your help!

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5162020/896341

Comment: @Harmen So true. I wish I could upvote that twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('.detailsholder').hide().animate({"top": '-520px'},1).fadeIn(500).delay(5000).animate({'top': "-260px",'easing': "easeInElastic"},400).delay(5000).animate({'top': "0px",'easing': "easeInElastic"},400);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want each `delay()` to occur after the animation has finished, in which case you should put it into the callback. As it stands now, the delay will be running as the animation occurs.

Also, as the comments say you should really chain your statements and add semi-colons to your line endings.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong in line 6 of your code (I splitted that line into several here for better reading:

```
$('.detailsholder')
.delay(5000)
.animate({'top': "-260px",'easing': "easeInElastic"}, 400)
.delay(5000)
.('.detailsholder') // The method is missing here!
.animate({'top': "0px",'easing': "easeInElastic"},400);
```

Note: You should also chain your jQuery code and put a semicolon after each command.

Comment: "The method is missing here!" ?

Comment: This doesn't work because it's your code? Look at the comment you forgot the method in that line.

Answer (score 0):

You can also queue events since delay only applies to the animation queue.

I have created this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/Veg59/1/ .

You can also have a look to this other post : [How to delay jquery animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583942/how-to-delay-jquery-animation) .

Answer (score 0):

Here a **[solution](http://jsfiddle.net/e6QeF/)** for you;

```
$('.detailsholder')
    .hide()
    .css('top', '200px')
    .fadeIn(500)
    .delay(2000)
    .animate({'top': "100px", 'easing': "easeInElastic"}, 400)
    .delay(2000)
    .animate({'top': "0px", 'easing': "easeInElastic"}, 400);
```

You might consider using an ID rather than a class as your animation seems quite unique.

Enjoy! :)